# AngularJS - Ng-model becomes null after changing view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page called **Personal Info** page with assigned **ng-models**.

e.g.

```
<input type = "text" name = "foo_name" ng-model = "foo.name" />
<input type = "text" name = "foo_address" ng-model = "foo.address" />
<input type = "text" name = "foo_age" ng-model = "foo.age" />
```

Then, there's a **Continue** button that redirects to a new page called **Other Details**.

The **Continue** button is validating all required fields if filled in. It's also returning a log if all fields are validated - either:

SUCCESS

```
{result:
    { error: null }
}
```

FAIL

```
{result:
    { error:
         {
            blah blah blah
         }
    }
}
```

In the Other Details page, it's just a GRID of the details entered on the previous page. And then, there's an "Edit" button in this page if they wanted to edit something on their personal info.

I'm using ng-model to retrieve the data being stored in the **saveDetailsInfo** service.

```
$scope.retrieveData = function(dataFromService) {
    $scope.foo = {
        name: dataFromService.entry.name,
        address: dataFromService.entry.address,
    }
}
```

Then, it's showing nicely and properly on its respective fields. The problem is if I'm trying to hit the **"Continue"** button again to save my changes. It's returning an error that these fields are already **undefined**, although the values have been printed and populated on the input fields.

Why has it become null?

Comment: At the beginning of your controller put: $scope.foo = { name:'', address:'', age:'' }; see if that fixes it

Comment: Please post more code.
What exactly does the continue button do?

Comment: The Continue function is just checking if all fields required are filled. Then it has the part 'var data = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($scope.formName));' where data is the params when the service is being called. I think I've done it right, but weird that it's returning 'undefined' when I tried to log one of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate the problem...but a quick fix is to check if the value is null on the continue function and if it's null then read the value from the ng-model again(as it's shown in the dom tree) and then using those data to initialize and continue what you need to do with the data.

Many times this happen because the function is initialized before the dom gets it data and hence null...